# Replace code in plugin template

Tags: plugins, customization

In plugin, I have following code in `function`:

```
$return_string .= '<li class="wpc-category ' . $class . '"><a href="'. get_option('catalogue_page_url') .'">All Products</a></li>';
```

Now I want to put following condition :

```
<?php $currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');
      if($currentlang=="en-US"): ?>
     All Products 
<?php else: ?>Dummy Text
<?php endif;?>
```

I want to replace All products . Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Just as a heads up, If this is a Plugin downloaded from WordPress and you edit code in the plugin folder that code will be overwritten whenever the plugin updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');
if($currentlang=="en-US") 
    $link_text = 'All Products'; 
else
    $link_text = 'Dummy Text';
?>

$return_string .= '<li class="wpc-category ' . $class . '"><a href="'. get_option('catalogue_page_url') .'">' . $link_text . '</a></li>';
```